# RelativeLayout occupying full width

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the following layout and the output is this:

[image]

How can I ensure that grey background is only applicable for the content.. Why is it occupying full width when I have specified `wrap_content` for the `RelativeLayout` containing grey background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="17dp"
    android:paddingLeft="17dp"

    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bubble" android:layout_gravity="right" android:gravity="right"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/back" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_reply_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat_user_reply"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"


            android:src="@drawable/ic_single_tick"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_reply_timing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/chat_user_reply"

            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_reply_status"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/user_reply_status"
            android:text="17:10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chat_user_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/user_reply_timing"

            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="sample" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sir have you tried on a diff screen size device? and what is the resolution of the greyimage

Comment: Its not an image, its a shape drawable(rectangle) with a radius. It has nothing to do with screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove android:weightSum="1" from the first RelativeLayout.

It better though to use a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Try this layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample sample"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10 17:10"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_power_off"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with this layout is that if text view text is large, the imageview is pushed out of screen

Comment: I made some changes to the code. If the text on the TextView are too long they will create a new line. The only thing that you would need is to change the android:layout_width of the LinearLayout if you really need to.

Comment: I have tried it. See the result https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2YYeUWScLRvUWxFTUpGNF9mcEhMYUZRYTQ1S1BSTkVrTVQ4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the results vary with varying lengths. The relativelayout with right to left positioning works perfectly, just the relativelayout is expanded to whole screen

Comment: It doesn't look you are using the code I've provided you. The TextView used for the message should have android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" also the ImageView needs to have a constant size. My code does what you asked for, which is "How can I ensure that grey background is only applicable for the content?".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the background is too big? Why don't you try setting the background to the text field only

Comment: Its just a shape drawable(rectangle) and want to appear on the whole content not just the textview

Answer (score 0):

Create a new ImageView and put it inside your RelativeLayout at the bottom (first item) and adjust it's left edge to the TextView you need. You can set margins and padding to your needs too.